# WSO2 ESB how to securize a proxy by default when deploy

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a lot of proxies in WSO2 ESB that I have to securize. I need them to be securized using Username Token when deploy, instead of browsing to the dashboard and enabling it one by one.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess currently, you need to use management console and do it. From the UI,  it is calling a backend web service. You can automate process by automating this backend web service. This web service is exposed by following component [1].  You can use soapui or some client program to automate this web service.

[1] http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/components/security/org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt/

Comment: Hi, can u give same examples about how to use this sevice. I have had a look to the javascript ESB console code and the resquests for enabling security are post resquests, instead of soap calls.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar requirement, here is how I solved it

[Apply Role security to WSO2 ESB Proxy using Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567198/apply-role-security-to-wso2-esb-proxy-using-java-api/25568594#25568594)

Also you can find the test case here on how to use the methods

http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/tags/carbon/3.2.3/products/bps/2.1.1/modules/integration/org.wso2.bps.management.test/src/test/java/org/wso2/bps/management/SecurityTest.java

Well here how the code snippet goes to secure any proxy service with default security scenarios of WSO2 ESB. In WSO2 ESB "scenario1" signifies Usernametoken based security. Now if you wish to secure your proxy with scenario1 follow the below code snippet:

```
  public void applySecurityOnService(String serviceName, String policyId,
        String[] userGroups, String[] trustedKeyStoreArray,
        String privateStore)
        throws SecurityAdminServiceSecurityConfigExceptionException,
        RemoteException {
    ApplySecurity applySecurity;
    applySecurity = new ApplySecurity();
    applySecurity.setServiceName(serviceName);
    applySecurity.setPolicyId("scenario" + policyId); //scenario1 i.e. for Usernametoken security policyId should be 1
    applySecurity.setTrustedStores(trustedKeyStoreArray);
    applySecurity.setPrivateStore(privateStore);
    applySecurity.setUserGroupNames(userGroups);
    stub.applySecurity(applySecurity);
    _logger.info("Security Applied Successfully");
}
```

Here is how you may call this method from your client class:

```
 applySecurityOnService("MyProxy", "1", new String[]{"TestRole"}, new String[]{"wso2carbon.jks"}, "wso2carbon.jks");
```

Comment: While those links might answer the question it's best to summarize the linked content here (in case the links break).

Comment: Hi, I finally solved it using the parameters, policy from registry and allowRoles, so the proxy is secured on deploy.